# SQLAlchemy: No such column for existing colum

Tags: python, sql, group-by, sqlalchemy, subquery

I'm trying to write a query to be used as a `column_property`.

Tables description (relevant fields):

- **Session**

  - environment_id (foreign key on Environment table key below)
  - session_id
  - start_time (column_property)
  - end_time (column_property)
- **Run**

  - session_id (matches the session_id in the Session table)
  - test_id (foreign key on Test table key below)
  - start_time
  - end_time
- **Test**

  - key (primary key)
  - environment_id (foreign key on Environment table key below)
- **Environment**

  - key (primary key)

I'm trying to calculate the *session start time*, by selecting all of the *runs* that match through the *test* table the *environment* for the given *session*. Then getting the minimum value of the *start_time*.

My first attempt for `start_time` was as follows:

```python
start_time = column_property(
     select([func.min(Run.start_time)]).
     where(Run.session_id == session_id).
     where(Environment.key == environment_id))
```

But that gave for all the environments in a given session the same `start_time`.

I tried improving it (see below).

But that fails with the following error:
`sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: sessions.environment_id`

Although I see the environment_id defined a few lines higher up:

```python
class Session(BASE):
    key = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    session_id = Column(Integer)
    environment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("environments.key"))
    environment = relationship("Environment")

    start_time = column_property(
        select([func.min(Run.start_time)]).
        select_from(
            Run.__table__.join(Test.__table__, Run.test_id == Test.key)).
        where(Run.session_id == session_id).
        group_by(environment_id))
```

According to my trial and error with SQL I'm trying to generate the following query:

```sql
    SELECT MIN(runs.start_time) FROM
        runs JOIN tests ON runs.test_id = tests.key
    WHERE runs.session_id = ? GROUP BY environment_id
```

I'd really much appreciate your help

**UPDATE: I updated the `Session` class code**

Comment: Have you maybe created the table `sessions` and then made changes to your model, adding those columns?

Comment: See the update. The definition of `start_time` is part of the class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I was getting the error `sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: sessions.environment_id` was because I was trying to select from a join between the `Run` table and the `Test` table. So I can't `GROUP BY` a field from the `Session` table.

The solution is basically a cross between both attempts:

```python
    start_time = column_property(
        select([func.min(Run.start_time)]).
        select_from(Run.__table__.join(Test)).
        where(Run.session_id == session_id).
        where(Test.environment_id == environment_id))
```

So I needed to create a `JOIN` as I deduced from my second attempt. But instead of `GROUP BY` I needed another `WHERE` statement so as to select only those runs which had the given session ID and that belonged to a Test with the given environment ID.

Answer (score 0):

Add the table name before the field. i.e

```
where(Run.session_id == Session.session_id).
group_by(Session.environment_id)).
```

Comment: That won't work as the `column_property` is within the `Session` class definition. See update.